# Memory allocation for override properties of abstract classes

Tags: c#, properties, abstract-class

I have an abstract class where I define a bunch of properties. Will this cause each instance of a child class (which needs an override property) to allocate memory for this property? The reason I ask is that some child classes will need the property, and some never, but other classes do access the property of the abstract class.

And does it make a difference whether I override it like this:

```
public override int someProperty {get; set;}
```

Or like this (keeping the get and set methods empty on purpose, because maybe no memory is allocated for the associated field?)

```
    public override int someProperty
    {
        get
        {
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
```

First question so I hope I'm asking everything correctly.

Comment: Are you actually running low on memory? I wouldn't worry about it unless you are creating millions of these instances.

Comment: The second form isn't even valid - the `get` implementation *has* to return a value.

Comment: Blorgbeard, I'm not. But it will be a lot of them yes.

Comment: Jon Skeet, that's a bit silly of me. Just imagine it says `int dummyInt = 0; return dummyInt;` I imagine that would work. Or however I would deal with invalid get queries.

Comment: @JonSkeet: _has_ to return a value? `throw new NotImplementedException();` :)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: True. Cannot reach the end of the block normally.

Comment: Or if you like to [live dangerously](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkzMA1jrm00&t=0m44s)... `return someProperty;` >.>

Comment: Maybe these properties are not needed in that abstract class?

Comment: Properties doesn't allocate memory, fields does. so you have to be concerned about fields you're using not properties. and obviously `Auto implemented Properties` introduce their backing field.

Comment: Well, I figured that `Auto implemented Properties` introduce backing fields. I just wondered how that works with abstract properties, where I cannot make custom methods for `get` and `set`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A property does not (necessarily) imply storage is allocated. Properties are just syntactic sugar around `get` and `set` methods. Unless you also have a field to store the data, they are just pairs of methods.

Example: If your base class has properties like this:

```
public virtual int SomeProperty { get { return 0; } { set { } }
```

Then no storage is allocated.

But if you use an auto-property:

```
public virtual int SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Then there is an automatic backing field generated, for which storage is allocated.

Comment: In this case, if I use the override method like your first method (with `override` rather than `virtual`), for each child class not needing the property, I'm good to go memory-wise?

Comment: Yes, if the base class has no backing field, and the child class has no backing field, then there's no storage. If you make the property `virtual` rather than `abstract`, you don't even have to override it unless you want to use it.

Comment: Well, the base class and property are both `abstract`, so I guess there is no backing field? And I'll try using `virtual` over `abstract`. I thought I had to use `abstract` properties and methods for `abstract` classes.

Comment: Just tried, works fine. Makes me wonder about my decision to implement an abstract class to begin with.